# How safe is it for a British Sunni Muslim to visit Iran with family?

Tags: uk-citizens, iran, religion, islam

I'm a British Sunni Muslim considering a visit to Iran with my wife and 2 year old daughter. Some online research suggested that Sunni Muslims in Iran are persecuted quite badly. Do any Sunni Muslim tourists have any experiences to share? Also, in which part of Tehran can I find Sunni Muslims, their restaurants, mosques, etc?

This is what I've found so far:
http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2127089

Comment: I think the Sunni vs. Shia perspective might be better suited for islam.SE.

Comment: For anyone interested, I've added this question to [my list of good examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989) in support of adding features to address crossover questions across the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 10):

I Googled and found these 9 Sunni mosques in Tehran,

```
1 - Sadeghiyeh mosque, located at the Sadeghiyeh second circle,
2 - Tehran-Pars mosque, located on Delavaran street,
3 - Al-Quds mosque, located at 20km on the old road,
4 - Persian-Gulf mosque, located in Fath,
5 - Al-Nabi mosque, located in Shahrak Danesh,
6 - Haft-Choob mosque, located in Mallard road,
7 - Vahidiye mosque, located in Shahriar,
8 - Nasim-e-Shahr mosque, located in Akbarabad,
9 - Razy-Abad mosque, located in Shahriar forked-road.
```

Since I am not so much into religion I can't give much information about Sunnis in Iran but I think there shouldn't be a major problem for most branches of Sunnis in Iran (Considering the fact that [9% of population of Iran itself are Sunnis](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/ir.html) which equals to almost 7M). However I do believe they are not really good with [Wahhabis](http://www.tehrantimes.com/component/content/article/52-guests/108546-wahhabism-a-great-threat-to-islamic-civilization).

Hope I am right and could help.

Comment: Thanks Hatef, where did you get this list from?

Comment: You're welcome. I've done a search in Farsi and this list came up which was published in different websites! I just translated some of the terms to the English but kept the common street names in Farsi. I think if you print the list and take with you most people would be able to help you to find the exact address in Tehran.

Comment: @Hatef +1! But you could improve the answer even more by adding those Farsi websites as sources. People can use Google Translate to check them out.